# Try to use variants and table personalisation on SAPUI5 SmartTable

Tags: sapui5, hana

I want to use the variants to customise different filter and table variants on a SAP Fiori application, that use SAP Hana Cloud and Java backend.

As a background info:
I'm using a smartTable that is connected to the smartFilter by filterId property. On the table/filter I am able to access directly the data from the metadata by filing the entitySet / entityType property. I am using a real server not a mock server. In the table the properties regarding the personalization and variants are enabled (useTablePersonalisation="true", useVariantManagement="true"). I see that I have to specify the persistencyKey  so that variants can display on the UI, but i don't know what value should i complete it with.
I read that  smartTable and smartFilter are using SmartVariantManagement(a custom control of VarinatManagement) to accessed directly (without user interaction) SAPUI5 Flexibility Services regarding personalization data and management of the variant. But on SAP Help it says that:

- Flexibility services are currently not available in SAP Hana Cloud Platform.
- The services run on the ABAP front-end server and NetWeaver 7.31 SP11 or higher

Here is the link: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/a8/e55aa2f8bc4127923b20685a6d1621/frameset.htm

It is possible to use the variants and personalization?
How can I do it regardind my application specification?
Does anyone have an example application?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can use them both at the same time.
For me the `useTablePersonalisation="true"` is working without any other changes. Rearding the useVariantManagement="true", I use `showVariantManagement="true"` also, and as you said persistencyKey="SmartFilter_Explored" is also needed to see Variant Management icon.
This is an example: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable/preview

For me I can not test the variant management functionality when running the app from webide as it is needed an existing user for you. So I can test it only, when running it on launchpad.

PersistencyKey identifies the storage area and saves/retrieves the variants currently used.
This page helps you with persistency key (under Page Variant section):
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/06a4c3ac1cf545a7b51864e7f3aa02da

I hope it helped.

Comment: http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080 is accessible only inside SAP's network.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I changed it to: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/06a4c3ac1cf545a7b51864e7f3aa02da